Explanation of type comparison using switch-case in Dart
Why doesn't this work
Type type = double;

switch (type) {
  case int:
    print('int');
  case double:
    print('double');
}

But this does
switch (type) {
  case const (int):
    print('int');
  case const (double):
    print('double');
}

What is const (Type) for? It looks like turning a class or type (hereinafter simply class) into its constant form. Well, firstly, turning something into a constant seems wrong to me, like, we just define them and forbid redefining them. What's the point of making something immutable only for a certain period, instead of just not changing it? Secondly, isn't the class itself immutable during runtime, which in essence can be perceived as a constant?
Why not just use the first form to write switch-case for comparing types? Either I don't understand what const (Type) does, or I don't understand what a class is (if so, then I hope only in Dart).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What does "doesn't this work" mean here? When I paste your first code snippet into dartpad.dev, it prints double - which is what I'd expect it to do.

Types are pretty useless at runtime, and have quirks as you've noticed.  The proper form for switching on an object's type is switch(obj) { case int(): "it's an int"; ... }

The code works.
The question might be promted by lint warning about not using case int:.
It's discouraged because people have mistakenly written switch (someValue) { case int: ...} and expected it to check whether the value is an integer.
Instead it checks if the value is a Type object equal to int, with no warning about it not being able to match (because it could hypothetically be an instance of a sub class of the switched-on type that implements Type).
You should use int _ or int() to check whether the value is an integer, and to avoid the lint warning, you can use == int or const (int) to emphasize that you really do want to compare to a Type object.
The const (expression) is a way to put any constant expression into a pattern. Writing const (int) doesn't mean anything other than int, it's only there to silence the lint by telling it that you know you're comparing to a constant Type object.
Generally, comparing Type objects is usually a sign of a class design that doesn't match the problem. It's also usually fragile and error prone code.
